# how to get data value from user control in parent class of c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Control 1:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cntrlIPSEntry.ascx.cs" inherits="ServiceManagement.Control.cntrlIPSEntry" %>    
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

another control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerInfo.ascx.cs" Inherits="ServiceManagement.Control.CustomerInfo" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/cntrlIPSEntry.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="cntrlIPSEntry" %>

 <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

in C# i want to catch control 1 data of txtModel

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //??
}
```

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cntrlIPSEntry.ascx.cs" Inherits="ServiceManagement.Control.cntrlIPSEntry" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"
                             >
                </asp:TextBox>

Comment: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerInfo.ascx.cs" Inherits="ServiceManagement.Control.CustomerInfo" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Control/cntrlIPSEntry.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="cntrlIPSEntry" %>
<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>

Comment: Use the "edit" button to add the code to your post. Noone can read code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `FindControl`. You first find the Control holding the TextBox in the Parent, in this case the Control with ID `WebUserControl1`. Then it's just a matter of finding the correct TextBox and cast it as one.

```
TextBox textBox = this.Parent.FindControl("WebUserControl1").FindControl("txtModel") as TextBox;
Label1.Text = textBox.Text;
```